# Subtracting two fields in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to loop through objects from my database in the template and one of the things I want to display is the difference between two of the fields in the table.  Is there a clean way to do this:

```
{% for game in games %}
<tr>
    <td width=100><p>{{ game.name }} </p></td>
    <td width=300><p>{{ game.campaign }} </p></td>
    <td width=90><p>{{ game.num_Players }} </p></td>
    <td width=90><p>{{ game.num_Players - game.accepted_Characters }}</p></td>
    <td width=90><p>{{ game.standing_Requests }}</p></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

?  Where game is a table object with all those fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django templates are designed not to do computation.  You should adjust your `games` list in the view, then display it in the template:

```
# views.py
for game in games:
    game.chars_diff = game.num_Players - game.accepted_Characters


# template.html
<td><p>{{ game.chars_diff }}</p></td>
```

Comment: Would that mean adding a new field to the table or could I just add the variable like you have?