# django - how to pass a result of subtraction for each object to template through context

Tags: python, django

In my application I have a list of trainings. One field on this list should display a result of subtraction of two variables.
How to pass properly a result of subtraction for each training to template through context? My code doesn't work correctly - it looks like it is some problem with loop for, because subtraction is calculated for first training and then it is propagated for the rest of trainings. Please give me some advice what should be done to work as expected.

views.py

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    """Home Page with list of trainings"""
    template_name = 'club/training_list.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['trainings'] = Training.objects.filter(state="A", training_date__gte=now).order_by('training_date', 'start_time')
        for each_training in context['trainings']:
            context ['diff'] = each_training.availability - each_training.counter
            return context
        return context
```

models.py

```
class Training(models.Model):
    """Class for plan training"""
    STATE = (
        ('A', 'Active'),
        ('I', 'Inactive'),
    )
    name = models.ForeignKey('TrnDesc')
    instructor = models.ForeignKey('Instructor')
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(default='00:00:00')
    availability = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=15)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATE, default='A')
    training_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    counter = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name
```

training_list.html

```
{% extends 'club/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Fitness Classes</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Join Us</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br></br>
    {% regroup trainings by training_date as date_list %}
    {% for date in date_list %}
        <div class="panel panel-default">


            <div class="panel-heading">{{date.grouper|date:"l, d F o"}}</div>


            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 20%">Training name</th>
                    <th style="width: 30%">Training description</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Instructor</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Start time</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">End time</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Left</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%">Actions</th>
                </tr>


                {% for training in date.list %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{training.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{training.name.desc}}</td>
                    <td>{{training.instructor}}</td>
                    <td>{{training.start_time|time:"H:i"}}</td>
                    <td>{{training.end_time|time:"H:i"}}</td>
                    <td>{{diff}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'book' training_id=training.pk%}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Book</button></a></td>
                </tr>

                {% endfor %}    
            </table>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You overwrite the context variable repeatedly in a loop (and then return in the first iteration). It may be easier to just do this in the template,

Comment: You mean to do sth like that in template: {{training.availability}} - {{training.counter}} ? But this solution only displays values of availability and counter. It doesn't calculate them.

Comment: ["django subtract"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=django+subtract)...

Comment: Thanks. Solution which is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199977/subtracting-two-fields-in-a-template helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtracting two fields in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199977/subtracting-two-fields-in-a-template)